# how to assign a two-dimensional variable to an array

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a program to generate up to ten "zombies" in pygame. however, i am having trouble with the following code:

```
ZOMBIE = pygame.image.load('zombie.png')

zombieamount = 0

**zombiepos(1) = [-1,-1]
zombiepos(2) = [-1,-1]
zombiepos(3) = [-1,-1]
zombiepos(4) = [-1,-1]
zombiepos(5) = [-1,-1]
zombiepos(6) = [-1,-1]
zombiepos(7) = [-1,-1]
zombiepos(8) = [-1,-1]
zombiepos(9) = [-1,-1]
zombiepos(10) = [-1,-1]**

while True:
    for i in range (1,10):
         time.sleep(5)
         x=randint(0,30)
         y=randint(0,20)
         **zombiepos(i) = [x,y]**
         global zombieamount
         zombieamount =+ 1

     for i in range (1,zombieamount):
         window.blit(ZOMBIE, (zombiepos(i)[0]*TILESIZE, zombiepos(i)[1]*TILESIZE))
```

however, the program highlights the bolded staement, stating "can't assign to function call" my teacher stated that it might be because i am trying to assign a two-dimensional variable to a one-dimensional array. Any tips?

Comment: `zombiepos(1)` looks like a function call. You haven't shown a function called that, or declared a variable called `zombiepos`, so it's hard to see what you're trying to do. Are you just mixing round `()` and square `[]` brackets at random?

Comment: No offence, but looks like your teacher is not familiar with python. In python `()` are used to invoke a function. To access array element you should use `[]`. So this is just a syntactic error, voting to close.

Comment: It _certainly_ looks like you're asking the wrong teacher..

Comment: What's `zombiepos`? What's the point of `zombieamount`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell python your zombiepos is an array before you assign to it through indexing:

```
zombiepos = []
for _ in range(10):
    zombiepos.append([-1,-1])
```

you'll have to change the for statement in the while to range(10) as well.

the global statement is unnecessary. you'd need to use it if you were accessing zombieamounts in a function.

also, as mentioned in some of the comments to your code, when you access the items within zombiepos you need to use square brackets [] not parentheses

Comment: you can do this simplier: `zombiepos = [ [-1,-1] for _ in range(10) ]`

Comment: `[[-1,1]]*10` would work too